# How do I add an option that sets a flag to a document class?

Tags: documentclass-writing, package-options

I want to add an option that sets a flag to a document class. That is, I want to be able to type

```
\documentclass[foo]{class}
```

and get one type of behavior, and type

```
\documentclass{class}
```

to get a different type of behavior. I'm thinking I should do it like this in the class file:

```
\newif\if@foo
\@foofalse
...
\DeclareOption{foo}{\@footrue}
...
\if@foo
...
\else
...
\fi
```

Will this work? Could this cause a problem if a package I use in the document also has a `\newif\if@foo` in it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [LaTeX2e for class and package writers](http://www.latex-project.org/guides/clsguide.pdf) contains some examples of this within section **3.3 Declaring options** (p 12). It pertains to the declaration of package and class options. The following snippets are taken from there:

> An option is declared as follows:
>
> ```
> \DeclareOption{<option>}{<code>}
> ```
>
> For example, the `dvips` option (slightly simplied) to the `graphics`
>   package is implemented as:
>
> ```
> \DeclareOption{dvips}{\input{dvips.def}}
> ```
>
> This means that when an author writes `\usepackage[dvips]{graphics}`,
>   the file `dvips.def` is loaded. As another example, the `a4paper`
>   option is declared in the `article` class to set the `\paperheight`
>   and `\paperwidth` lengths:
>
> ```
> \DeclareOption{a4paper}{%
>   \setlength{\paperheight}{297mm}%
>   \setlength{\paperwidth}{210mm}%
> }
> ```
>
> Sometimes a user will request an option which the class or package has
>   not explicitly declared. By default this will produce a warning (for
>   classes) or error (for packages); this behaviour can be altered as
>   follows:
>
> ```
> \DeclareOption*{<code>}
> ```
>
> For example, to make the package `fred` produce a warning rather than
>   an error for unknown options, you could specify:
>
> ```
> \DeclareOption*{%
>   \PackageWarning{fred}{Unknown option `\CurrentOption'}%
> }
> ```
>
> Then, if an author writes `\usepackage[foo]{fred}`, they will get a
>   warning
>
> ```
> Package fred Warning: Unknown option `foo'.
> ```

Subsequent sections contain some examples of classes constructed from others, which would be good to review.

Using options that are common to other packages could be problematic. However, since you have a choice over the boolean (or macros) associated with the option, choose it to be unique to your class. Authors typically include some form of package reference in the macros. For example, the [`tufte-latex` bundle](http://ctan.org/pkg/tufte-latex) prepends most commands and booleans with `@tufte` to avoid possible clashes.